# Different report by logged in user

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am new to PowerBI and I have a project where I store my data on MySQL( or I will use MSSQL) server. Each user has a defined ID. Is it possible to create a user login or something like that that would show reports for different users?

Login screen with powerBI shortcode will be on my website and I would like to show powerBi report by logged user. Report screen will be the same every time, but with different numbers for different user.

I am sorry for this question, but I am new to powerBI. Is it even possible to create something like this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, you need to look at Row Level Security https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at Row-level security.
Row-level security (RLS) allows you to restrict logged in user's access to report's data, i.e. you can show different part of your data based on logged in user.
You can setup RLS in Power BI Desktop. You can create different roles that can be assigned by generating the embed token while embedding.
Refer docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

While embedding, generate embed token based on the user who has logged in and assign the roles to it.    Refer docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security